# Check two items are in a list but not in a set order?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list

```
listOfStations = ['FSTL40503', 'LHSL40503', 'WEHL40503', 'BKGL40503', 'DDKL40503', 'RNML40503', 'PFLL40503', 'GRYL40503']
```

I want to check that FSTL40503 comes first and then PFLL40503 comes second. I currently can find if both exist, but it doesn't respect the order of what I want.

```
toBeChecked=['PFLL40503','FSTL40503']
if all(item in listOfStations for item in toBeChecked):
    print "Both stations found in order, in list"
```

This currently prints which it shouldn't do as it's not the right route.

I also tried to join both entries in the list to make a string and check but I think I'm confusing what needs to be done:

```
z= ''.join(toBeChecked)
  print z
  for char in z:
    if char not in listOfStations:
      print listOfStations
      continue
    else:
      listOfStations = listOfStations[listOfStations.index(char) + 1:]    
    confirmedTrainList.append(trainList[i])
```

Comment: If they need to be in position 0 and 1, you can just check the first and second item in your list, making sure they are the ones you need. If they just need to be in this order at any index, you can use `l.index("FSTL40503")` to retrieve the index of your element, then checking the following element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get an iterator over `listOfStations` which will consume the list as it searches, so it never considers the same element twice.

```
def contains_in_order(container, items):
    it = iter(container)
    return all(item in it for item in items)

should_not_work = ['PFLL40503', 'FSTL40503']
should_work     = ['FSTL40503', 'PFLL40503']

listOfStations = ['FSTL40503', 'LHSL40503', 'WEHL40503', 'BKGL40503', 'DDKL40503', 'RNML40503', 'PFLL40503', 'GRYL40503']

print(contains_in_order(listOfStations, should_not_work))
# False
print(contains_in_order(listOfStations, should_work))
# True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the index of each station:

```
listOfStations = ['FSTL40503', 'LHSL40503', 'WEHL40503', 'BKGL40503', 'DDKL40503', 'RNML40503', 'PFLL40503', 'GRYL40503']
toBeChecked=['PFLL40503','FSTL40503']

def check(to_check, big_list):
    try:
        return big_list.index(to_check[0]) < big_list.index(to_check[1])
    except ValueError:
        return False


check(['PFLL40503','FSTL40503'], listOfStations)
# False
check(['LHSL40503', 'GRYL40503'], listOfStations)
# True
```

Comment: that is actually very simple and nice. +1

Comment: It also searches the big list twice, only handles 2 search values, and doesn’t work for non-unique list contents (it will report false when looking for [A,B] in [B,A,B]).

Answer (score 0):

I find the following quite elegant:

```
def in_order_exist(lst, to_find):
    try:
        lst[:lst.index(to_find[1])].index(to_find[0])
        return True
    except:
        return False

print(in_order_exist(listOfStations, toBeChecked))  # True
```

The idea is to check whether the first element exists in the sublist defined by the beginning of the list and the second element.

---

I am assuming:

- two elements only (because of OP's title)
- correct ordering of the `toBeChecked` list.